# Xamarin Forms Map - 3D transition effect

Tags: 3d, uwp, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm trying to transit my 2D view to a 3D view once a reach a defined level of zoom for a PCL project [**MAP 3D Project - Github**](https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/Map/Map3DProject)

So, wat did I do (on the PCL part), I created a *customMap.cs* an object which is basically an object that inherits from Xamarin.Forms.Map : `public class CustomMap : Map`

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Just for my test since I can't find the way to find the current location of the camera
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty LocationProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Location), typeof(Position), typeof(CustomMap), new Position(47.942660, 0.261979));

    /// <summary>
    /// Assessor for Location property.
    /// </summary>
    public Position Location
    {
        get { return (Position)GetValue(LocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocationProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just for my test since I can't find the way to get the current zoom level
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ZoomLevelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ZoomLevel), typeof(Distance), typeof(CustomMap), new Distance());

    /// <summary>
    /// Assessor for ZoomLevel property.
    /// </summary>  
    public Distance ZoomLevel
    {
        get { return (Distance)GetValue(ZoomLevelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZoomLevelProperty, value); }
    }

    #region Constructor
    public CustomMap()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            CustomMap map = sender as CustomMap;
            if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
            {
                this.ZoomLevel = map.VisibleRegion.Radius;
            }
        };
        isMapLoaded = false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Additionnals
    private bool isMapLoaded;
    /// <summary>
    /// Method called from the renderer once the map is loaded
    /// </summary> 
    public void MapLoaded()
    {
        isMapLoaded = true;
        if (this.VisibleRegion != null)
        {
            this.ZoomLevel = this.VisibleRegion.Radius;
        }
    }
    public bool IsMapLoaded { get { return (isMapLoaded); } }
    #endregion
}
```

So now, in the renderer part, if we take a look at UWP (I have a Windows machine, so it makes my builds/test easier/faster to run on local x86), I made a basic renderer: `public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer`

```
/// <summary>
/// CustomRenderer for the CustomMap created in the PCL part.
/// This Renderer gives us the possibility to add/override some functionalities.
/// </summary>
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of the native map for this plateform.
    /// </summary>
    MapControl nativeMap;

    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of our Custom control declared in the PCL part.
    /// </summary>
    CustomMap customMap;

    /// <summary>
    /// We override the OnElementChanged() event handler to get the desired instance. We also use it for updates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">It contains either the NewElement or the OldElement</param>
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            customMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            nativeMap = Control as MapControl;

            nativeMap.Loaded += ((sender, re) =>
            {
                customMap.MapLoaded();
            });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The on element property changed callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/>Instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (this.customMap == null || this.nativeMap == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == CustomMap.ZoomLevelProperty.PropertyName)
            UpdateCameraView();
    }

    private async void UpdateCameraView()
    {
        if (customMap == null || nativeMap == null)
            return;

        if (nativeMap.Is3DSupported && customMap.IsMapLoaded)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set the aerial 3D view.
                nativeMap.Style = MapStyle.Aerial3DWithRoads;

                // Specify the location.
                BasicGeoposition hwGeoposition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = customMap.VisibleRegion.LatitudeDegrees, Longitude = customMap.VisibleRegion.LongitudeDegrees };
                Geopoint hwPoint = new Geopoint(hwGeoposition);
                // Create the map scene.
                MapScene hwScene = MapScene.CreateFromLocationAndRadius(hwPoint,
                                                                                     80, //show this many meters around
                                                                                     0, //looking at it to the North
                                                                                     60); //degrees pitch

                // Set the 3D view with animation.
                await nativeMap.TrySetSceneAsync(hwScene, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("------------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Debug.WriteLine("------------------------");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If 3D views are not supported, display dialog.
            ContentDialog viewNotSupportedDialog = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "3D is not supported",
                Content = "\n3D views are not supported on this device.",
                PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
            };
            await viewNotSupportedDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm facing two problems/questions. First, I have an exception which isn't catch by the `try {}` in the `private async void UpdateCameraView()` ==> `The program '[17780] Map3DProject.UWP.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.` I searched on internet and it says that I'm accessing a null value, which can't be really possible since I'm checking the value + I checked with a breakpoint and everything seem initialized..

Also, how can I manage the transition from 2D to 3D (when you reach x meters/miles of zoom) if I can't access the current camera region location values? Because, referring to [Display maps with 2D, 3D, and Streetside views documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#configure-the-map), I need a `Geopoint` to create a scene with a radius.

In this doc, I saw that you can also call `MapScene.CreateFromCamera(nativeMap.ActualCamera);`, however I can't apply any rotation value.. So, useless for me

If anyone has any suggestion about the logic or any answer about my problems, be welcome to let a comment !

Thank,

Max

Comment: Could you please tell in which code line you got the `Access violation` exception?

Comment: *// Set the aerial 3D view.* || `nativeMap.Style = MapStyle.Aerial3DWithRoads;`